# Ill effects from vetoing .DS_Store files on an SMB server?

Tags: finder, network, smb

I am in an environment where I have a Samba file server accessed by multiple users on both managed and unmanaged Macs.

I've noticed that performance in the Finder gets pretty terrible in folders with a lot of content. There is a `defaults` option to disable the local system from using or creating `.DS_Store` files on network shares that does do a great deal to help:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

This is easy enough to set on my managed systems, but I would like to do something more centralized for the unmanaged ones. [Samba has a veto files option](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_02.html) that should prevent those files from being written. However, I am not familiar enough with how Finder uses these to know what effect, if any, blocking these files would have.

Can I expect any bad behavior from the systems without the defaults option set if they are not allowed to generate these files?